# Do we need all 3 tags : Finance, Financial Economics, Financial Markets?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

How do these 3 tags differ? Can't we merge (some of) them?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance v. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-economics  v.
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-markets

Comment: This essentially boils down to what’s difference between finance and financial economics and there is not much difference. If you look at universities masters degree in finance would be more practical with larger emphasis placed on analysis from the investors/finance firm point of view while masters degree in financial economics would study financial markets in more rounded but less practical way. On other SE tags overlap as well, for example Cross-validated has separate tags for mean and average, I don’t see why having overlapping tag would be an issue

Comment: @1muflon1 Ought we merge the tags then?

Comment: I am personally in favor of having more granular tags, so if it would be up to me I would just keep them

Comment: I have very little opinion on tags, but am willing to hear other people's opinions on them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we merge [finance](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) and [financial-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-economics) unless we can define [whether and how they differ](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/41854) in any significant capacity.

It is harder to tell what to do with [financial-markets](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-markets) as it does not even have a Wiki and I have not investigated in any depth for what topics it is actually used.

Comment: I agree and would add the following.  In the context of Economics SE, it is implicit in any tag, whether it contains the word economics or not, that it relates to economics. So it's hard, for this site, to see any difference between finance and financial-economics.